# How do I SELECT LIKE '%' in mysql

Tags: mysql

I want to get all rows which consists of '%' in there

For example

```
|column A|column B|
| John | 23%45|
| Smith | 99 |
| Anne | 45 |
```

output:

```
|column A|column B|
| John | 23%45|
```

Comment: https://www.google.com.au/search?q=mysql+escape+like First result is https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-comparison-functions.html *To test for literal instances of a wildcard character, precede it by the escape character. If you do not specify the ESCAPE character, \ is assumed.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can skip it as any other other special character with a `\`

```
SELECT * FROM `MyTable` WHERE MyColumn Like "%\%%"
```

Comment: for mysql, i had to change a bit '%\\%%'